# Why is MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_BIT_RATE not availabe?

Tags: android

[MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_BIT_RATE](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaFormat.java;l=490?q=KEY_MAX_BIT_RATE&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain) is defined in the following file:

C:...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\media\MediaFormat.java

However, I cannot use it in an Android app and it is not in [the official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat) either. An app creates a MediaFormat by using MediaExtractor on a file and it has the key "max-bitrate" that corresponds to MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_BIT_RATE.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Update [2023-11-01]

A screenshot of C:...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\media\MediaFormat.java:

[image]

Comment: I can't see this constant in ..\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\media\MediaFormat.java in my laptop

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella I have just added a screenshot of C:...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-34\android\media\MediaFormat.java

Comment: I downloaded the source code of Android 34 and now I can see it, but previously looking at the compiled code this constant did not appear declared.